# mocking zustand store in next js with testing library and jest

Tags: next.js, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library, zustand

component-store.js:

```
  import { create } from 'zustand';
    export const componentStore = create((set) => ({
    ITEMS_PER_PAGE: 5,
    currentNoOfItems: 5,
    totalItem: '',
    showMoreItems: (totalItem) => {
    set((state) => {
      if (state.currentNoOfItems < totalItem) {
        return {
          currentNoOfItems: state.currentNoOfItems + state.ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
        };  
      } else {
        return { currentNoOfItems: state.ITEMS_PER_PAGE };
      }
    });
  },
  setTotalItem: (value) => set(() => ({ totalItem: value })),
}));
```

Table.js:
const { ITEMS_PER_PAGE,currentNoOfItems,totalItem } = componentStore();

want to mock this in the testing file to avoid the error

TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: nation. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

```
Ignored nodes: comments, script, style
<body>
  <div />
</body>
```

and the testing code is:

```
Home.test.jsx:
    import { render,screen } from '@testing-library/react';
    import CustomTable from '@/components/UI/Table/Table';
    const mockProps = {...has data}
    test('renders table headers correctly', () => {
    render(<CustomTable {...mockProps} />);
    screen.debug();
    const text = screen.getByText("nation")
    expect(text).toBeInTheDocument()
    });
```

Anyone help me to mock this store to avoid the error

I want the store to be mocked correctly so that I can use the values to be passed to the component and get the test passed

Need help from someone!